# Using a template in a backbone view that includes the parent element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am attempting to refactor my backbone views to have all HTML related markup in external templates. Ideally I would like to have the element that the view is attached to in the external template as well. At the moment I have:

The html template

```
    <h3 class="pull-left">Search</h3>
    <input id="customer-search-input" class="input-large search-query" placeholder="Cust #, Name, Suburb or Owner" />
    <button id="customer-search-show-all" class="btn pull-right">Show All</button>
    <span id="update-time" class ="pull-right"></span>
    <table id="customer-search-results-table" class="tablesorter tablesorter-dropbox">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Number</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Suburb</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="customer-list-results">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And the backbone view that consumes the template:

```
    define(['jquery','underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/customerSearch.html','text!templates/customerRow.html', 'jquery.tablesorter' ],
        function($, _, Backbone, customerSearchTemplate, customerRow) {

        // ... Other sub-views

        var CustomerSearch = Backbone.View.extend({
            id:'customer-search', // would prefer to have these
            className: 'well',    // in the template
            initialize: function(){
                this.$el.html(customerSearchTemplate);
                this.customerSearchInput = this.$("#customer-search-input");
            },
            events: {
                "click #customer-search-show-all": "showAll",
                "keyup #customer-search-input": "search"
            },
            search: function(){
                var filteredCustomers = this.collection.search(this.customerSearchInput.val(), ['id','companyName','suburb','businessContact']);
                this.customerSearchResultsView = new CustomerSearchResultsView({collection: filteredCustomers});
                this.customerSearchResultsView.render();
            },
            showAll: function() {
                this.customerSearchResultsView = new CustomerSearchResultsView({collection: this.collection});
                this.customerSearchResultsView.render();
            }
        });

        return CustomerSearch;
    });
```

Everything works but it would be great to be able to have the `id` and `className` as part of a wrapper div in the template. If I add this to the template then it appears correctly when rendered but is wrapped by another div by the backbone view.

I'm trying to decouple everything as much as possible.

Thanks!

---

**Update 17 Oct 2012**

Using the `view.setElement` method

```
    var CustomerSearch = Backbone.View.extend({
            template:_.template(customerSearchTemplate),
            initialize: function(){
                  this.setElement(this.template());
            },
            // ...
    });
```

with template

```
    <div id="customer-search" class="well">
            <h3 class="pull-left">Search</h3>
            // ...
    </div>
```

appears to work. Just wondering now if there is performance hit. Will report back.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594961/backbone-not-this-el-wrapping

Comment: Thanks @nikoshr. I thought I had read somewhere that one shouldn't use the setElement method unless setting an existing view element to a new one. I guess when using it as you describe the original backbone created `<div>` is overridden by the parent element from the template and this doesn't cause any problems because the original `<div>` was never appended to the DOM. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your template element within a script tag with an id.

```
<script id="custom-search" type="text/template">
    <h3 class="pull-left">Search</h3>
    <input id="customer-search-input" class="input-large search-query" placeholder="Cust #, Name, Suburb or Owner" />
    <button id="customer-search-show-all" class="btn pull-right">Show All</button>
    <span id="update-time" class ="pull-right"></span>
    <table id="customer-search-results-table" class="tablesorter tablesorter-dropbox">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Number</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Suburb</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="customer-list-results">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

And then, declare the following option in your view:

```
template : _.template($('#custom-search').html())
```

You will then be able to call :

```
this.$el.html(this.template());
```

in your initialize function. This will load the content of the script tag.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that this would only work if the script element is already loaded into the DOM? I am using the require.js text plugin to pull in the template so it exists in memory only. Also, wouldn't only the contents of the script tag get used and as such be added to an automatically generated `<div>` on the view?

Answer (score 2):

Why not 'wrap' your template in a parent div which includes the id / class (plus any other attribute you'd want to use)

```
<div id="customer-search" class="well"> ... </div>
```

and then use [setElement](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) to set the div as the View's **el**-ement.

(Note: I've never used the text plugin. But I see no reason you couldn't go with this method)

Also: [more about setElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586279/using-setelement-with-views-in-backbone).